# how can i dynamically generate a Gui in Unity3D via scripting?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to dynamically generate a Gui in Unity3D.
I've made a canvas with a panel as a child. I'm trying to populate this Panel with 7x4 images.

I receive a json object that has an x amount of items. Based on the amount of items I populate the panel with the amount of items received. For instance, if i receive a Json object with 28 items(7x4), I want the GUI to look like the following:

[image]

So like I've told, I made a canvas with a panel in the editor. In the script I made the following:

```
public GameObject canvas; //I use this to set the canvas after applying this script to an empty gameobject
public GameObject panel; // I do the same for the panel
```

In the Start method, i set the canvas as parent for the panel:

```
panel.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
```

Now that I set the panel as child to the Canvas, I want to generate 7x4 Images. Could anyone help me with this? What is the best way to generate multiple UI/Images and make it that it shows in the Panel like in the illustration?

Pretty new to Unity3D and I would like to get more familiair with scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix my code.
How I did it:
1. Add an empty gameobject to the editor
2. Add a canvas with a panel as a child
3. Add the following script to the empty gameobject in step 1:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class generateUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject canvas;
    public GameObject Panel;
    public GameObject image;
    int size = 40;

    private float scaler = 0.0125f;
    void Start()
    {
        Panel.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        GameObject[] tiles = new GameObject[size];
        Vector3 change = new Vector3(20 * scaler, 0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            tiles[i] = GameObject.Instantiate(image, transform.position, transform.rotation);

            tiles[i].transform.position += change;
            tiles[i].transform.SetParent(Panel.transform, false);
        }
    }
}
```

4: now add the following script to the canvas object:

```
using System.Collections
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI

public class DynamicGrid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int col,row;
    void Start()
    {
        RectTransform parent = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        GridLayoutGroup grid = gameObject.GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>();
        grid.cellSize = new Vector2(parent.rect.width / col, parent.rect.height / row);
    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

5: Set the canvas width to 1090 and height to 430

6: make a prefab from an image(100 by 100)

7: add a Grid Layout Group to the Panel

8: Set CellSize to 100 by 100 and spacing to 10 by 10

9: change the size in the generateUI script to a number you'd like to see

10: profit.

[image]

I now have the desired function. I followed @jour's suggestion to use a gridlayout, which I've used before while creating a mobile app with python's Kivy software.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you set the canvas as parent for the panel from code?

So, if you need to generate all your images dynamically from code, you could do the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class GUIBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject canvas; //I use this to set the canvas after applying this script to an empty gameobject
    public GameObject panel; // I do the same for the panel

    public Vector2 ImageViewCount; // 6 * 4
    public Vector2 ImageViewSize; // 80 * 80
    public Vector2 InitialImageViewPosition; // -300 * 250
    public Vector2 ImageViewPositionOffset; // 125 * 200


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
       GenerateImageView();
    }

    void GenerateImageView()
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < ImageViewCount.y; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < ImageViewCount.x; b++)
            {
                ImageViewBuilder(ImageViewSize, 
                new Vector2(InitialImageViewPosition.x + (ImageViewPositionOffset.x * b), 
                InitialImageViewPosition.y - (ImageViewPositionOffset.x * a)),
                panel.transform);
            }
        }
    }


    void ImageViewBuilder(Vector2 size, Vector2 position, Transform objectToSetImageView)
    {
        GameObject imageView = new GameObject("ImageView", typeof(RectTransform));
        RawImage image = imageView.AddComponent<RawImage>(); 
        //image.texture = Your Image Here
        RectTransform rectTransform = imageView.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rectTransform.sizeDelta = size;
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = position;
        imageView.transform.SetParent(objectToSetImageView, false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you could do is use Layout grid group on the panel, then set the images as children of the panel and force a rebuild layout

[Grid Layout](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html)

[Force rebuild layout](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate.html)